# Insert data based on non existence and different criteria's

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to add a row to my table only on two conditions but when inserting it retrieves error and I cannot figure it out

```
 Create PROC [dbo].[setvisitorqueue]
 @pid bigint = null , @vid int = NULL ,@regdate nvarchar(50)  =NULL 

 AS 

 declare @queNum int =null
 set @queNum = (select max([ticketNo]) + 1 from [dbo].[queue] where [ticketdate]= GetDate())
 if( @queNum is null) begin  set @queNum=1 end

 Declare @Tktt int = null  

 set @Tktt = (select count(queue.ticketid) from queue where (queue.pid = @pid )and (queue.ticketdate = GetDate()) and (queue.vid = @vid and queue.checked = 0))

 if (@Tktt is null ) 
 begin insert into queue (vid , pid , ticketNo , ticketdate ) Values (@Vid,@pid,@queNum,@regdate ) end
```

Its not working for me.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: only mention Return value =0 one row affected successfully

Comment: 1) Please [edit] any clarifications direction into your question. 2) Please show some sample data and expected results, both values in the table and the call to the SP with values.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Adding DDL for `queue` will remove some mysteries about the data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your SP with all the issues I spotted corrected with comments, and with best practices added. As noted by the other answer you can probably simplify things. I have just aimed to correct existing issues.

```
-- NOTES: Keep your casing and layout consistent
-- Always terminate statements with a semi-colon
-- Don't add un-necessary brackets, they just clutter the code
-- You also have a concurrency issue:
--   if this proc is called twice at the same time you could issue the same ticket number twice

create proc [dbo].[setvisitorqueue]
(
    @pid bigint = null,
    @vid int = null,
    -- Only every use a datetime/date datatype to store a datatime/date. Datetime2 is the current standard. Change precision to suit.
    @regdate datetime2(0) = null
)
as
begin
    -- Always start your SP with
    set nocount, xact_abort on;

    declare @queNum int = null;

    set @queNum = (
        select max([ticketNo]) + 1
        from dbo.[queue]
        -- This seems very unlikely to happen? It has to match down to the fraction of a second.
        where [ticketdate] = getdate()
    );

    if @queNum is null begin
        set @queNum = 1;
    end;

    declare @Tktt int = null;

    -- @Tktt will *never* be null after this, it may be zero though.    
    set @Tktt = (
        select count(*)
        from dbo.[queue]
        where pid = @pid
        -- This seems very unlikely to happen? It has to match down to the fraction of a second.
        and ticketdate = getdate()
        and vid = @vid and checked = 0
    );

    -- Handle 0 or null just in case
    -- if @Tktt is null -- THIS IS WHAT PREVENTED YOUR INSERT
    if coalesce(@Tktt,0) = 0 
    begin
        insert into dbo.[queue] (vid, pid, ticketNo, ticketdate)
            values (@Vid, @pid, @queNum, @regdate);
    end;

    -- Always return the status of the SP, 0 means OK
    return 0;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try it simple way like this?

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[setvisitorqueue]
@pid BIGINT = null,
@vid INT = NULL,
@regdate NVARCHAR(50) = NULL 
AS 
    
IF (
    SELECT COUNT(ticketid) 
    FROM [dbo].[queue] 
    WHERE checked = 0 and pid = @pid and vid = @vid and ticketdate = GetDate()
    ) = 0
INSERT INTO [dbo].[queue](vid  pid, ticketdate, ticketNo  ) 
SELECT @Vid, @pid, @regdate, ticketNo = IsNull(MAX([ticketNo]),0) + 1
FROM [dbo].[queue] 
WHERE [ticketdate]= GetDate();

RETURN;
GO
```

In this code I've done following:

1. Improved readability by Caps, intend, spaces, etc.
2. Eliminated variables - you do not need them in that code You do not
   need to calculate a "TicketNo" in the beginning if it won't be used.
   So, it will be calculated if needed within IF statement.
3. You do not need to use BEGIN-END on every transaction, single
   request IS a transaction

Not sure what your error was, but your procedure won't do anything just because when you do "COUNT" it returns a number. That means your "@Tktt" variable would never be NULL.

I guess your intention is to run the Insert statement when it is no records found and compared "COUNT" query to "0" value.

Comment: Thank You So Much it Worked For Me I Just Changed the GetTime() with @regdate and all is fine :)

Comment: "You do not need to use BEGIN-END on every transaction" I think you mean conditional statement block - because begin/end certainly doesn't define a transaction. However I would beg to differ, personally I always use a begin/end conditional statement block for clarify. Its too easy to make a mistake otherwise - but thats just my opinion.

Comment: @DaleK in this case, when there is single statement, it is not necessary. Definitely need it if there is a more complicated logic.
Personally I'm trying to avoid any unnecessary closes, because they make code less readable with possibility to not notice a mistake.
But that is "personal style" discussion.